# vb.net how to get a value with specific condition

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, conditional-statements, dataview

Thanks in advance. I searched but still don't know how to write.

[premise] 
I got a `DataView` of a Table, and filtered and sorted it.

[Table]
[After filtering, the table looks like this: ↓]

[image]

I want to get the names under different condition.
I wrote like this but it seems not correct.

```
If dv_Table1.Select("Code1 = '11'").Rows.Count > 0 Then
   drwWork.Item("Name") = dv_Table1.Item(0).Item("Name")

ElseIf dv_Table1.Select("Code1 = 12").Rows.Count > 0 Then
   drwWork.Item("Name") = dv_Table1.Item(0).Item("Name")
      If dv_Table1.Item(0).Item("Code2") = 1 Then
         drwWork.Item("Code") = Asterisk
      Else
      End If
Else
End If
```

My main goal is to get the different names according to different code 1.
I sorted the table by Order as well.
When the record number of [ code1 = 12, for example] is more than 2,
I want to get the two names in order ASC.

The `[ Item(0).Item("Name") ]` part maybe incorrect
I want to know the correct coding.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it right now, but:

Loop each row and add the names to lists:

```
Dim view = New DataView()
Dim list11 As New List(Of String)
Dim list12 As New List(Of String) ' You could make an array of List too

For Each row As DataRowView In view
    If row.Item("Code1").Equals(11) Then ' "11" If it's a string
        list11.Add(row.Item("Name"))
    ElseIf row.Item("Code1").Equals(12) Then ' "12" If it's a string
        list12.Add(row.Item("Name"))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! l got a different idea~~~ I will refer to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Datatable like :

```
Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(dv_Table1.DataSource, DataTable)

    Dim results1 = From myRow In dt.AsEnumerable() Where myRow.Field(Of [String])("Code1").Equals(11) Or myRow.Field(Of [String])("Code1").Equals(12)
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = results1.CopyToDataTable()

    For Each dw As DataRow In dt1.Rows
        drwWork.Item("Name") = dw.Item("Name")
        If dw.Item("Code2") = 1 Then
            drwWork.Item("Code") = Asterisk
            TableName.Rows.Add(drwWork)   'drwWork is a new row of an other datatable "TableName" for exemple
    Next
```